# My laptop screen flickers when on battery power

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics

My computer screen is flickering anytime it isn't plugged into AC power. I have figured out that this is an issue with my drivers and that I need to update them. But when I got to the Intel graphics drivers page there was no option to download drivers for Linux/Ubuntu. Is there is any way to update my Intel graphics drivers on Ubuntu?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo IdeaPad 2-in-1 4GB with an Intel Pentium 4415U.

The flickering looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Vl3EmyZX2s

Comment: Intel drivers are open source, so as they become available they are automatically updated.  Check the "software center" for system updates.

Comment: The question should be edited to remove mentioning upgrading the display driver - because the problem is the flickering screen.

Comment: "*I have figured out that this is an issue with my drivers and that I need to update them*" - How exactly did you come this conclusion?  I think it's the wrong one and this question is an XY Problem. The question should be rewritten to ask about your actual problem

Comment: If you're on 20.04; two kernel stack choices are offered.  There is the GA stack which remains the same the life of the product, and the HWE (hardware enablement) stack which updates during the first two years of the product (before finally settling on 22.04's GA stack). Which is default is selected by the ISO used at install time (though a server install lets you change it at install time). A `uname -r` will tell you what kernel (5.4 for GA, 5.11 for a fully updated HWE stack).  If using the GA stack, switching to HWE (you can have both installed and selected at grub) will update *driver*

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to upgrade your drivers. In older Ubuntu versions, the graphics driver was distributed as `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, which is updated as part of the system by Software Update. Since 21.04, the default Ubuntu session uses Wayland, which in turn uses DRI/DRM. Now, drivers are an integral part of the Linux kernel. Instead, you need to verify that the problem is exhibited in another operating system, or in the system firmware, to distinguish it from a hardware issue.

Comment: Hi folks - this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128191/discussion-on-answer-by-galexite-how-do-i-update-my-intel-graphics-display-drive) which will hopefully be more convenient. PyCoder01 if you had the issue on Windows it's probably a hardware issue

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for moving it to a chat!